# How to open iframe embedded google map's direction link in new tab?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, embed

I am embedding google map on my site by using the following code:

```
<iframe width='560' height='350' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0'   
        src='https://maps.google.com/maps?&amp;q="+ encodeURIComponent( result) +"&amp;output=embed&iwloc'>
</iframe>
```

Now if I click on the marker I can found direction link, which if I clicked, google maps find direction page is loading on the same page i.e my site.

Can I open this window in a separate tab so that user will not lost my site.

Comment: Do you really have to embedded google maps in a iFrame? Can't you simply use a div?

Comment: Thanks sabotero for your feedback.  that iframe I am embedding in a div only but the problem is how could I open direction in a new tab, we can found the direction if we click on the marker in a infowindow, I checked the parameters for the infowindow also but no luck.

Comment: What code did you try so far?

Comment: @srikantamondal  did you get any solution? please share if you got any solution.